# Can I do complex SQL style queries using javascript on a json data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, json

I am encountering a problem where in I need to manipulate a json result in a way that 
I could manipulate it with sql commands types.

like left joins and sum and group by

Thus anyone of you have encountered this lately?

I am currently using / exploring jsonsql javascript.. for the time being[image]

attach is the json file that i need to manipuate..

the new result should be like this

[image]

so Im guessing I needed to use left joins in order to be result in this kind of output.

My problem is like collecting all / some parts from the rows and making it a column
then putting it all together something like that???

I hope I made sense.. Thanks for all your response..

Comment: You cannot do *SQL* queries on JavaScript. JavaScript does not support SQL. Just to be pedantic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language provides you with some nice features, so there's no need for wrapping SQL over JS:

```
var data=[{"firstName":"Alice", "age":"16"},{"firstName":"Bob", "age":"18"} ... {"firstName":"Zacharias", "age":"37"}]
```

If you want to `SELECT * FROM json WHERE age>16`, you could do something equivalent in JS:

```
data.filter(function(x){ return x.age>16 })
```

If you want to `SELECT count(*) FROM json` you just write

```
data.length;
```

If you want to `SELECT avg(age) FROM json` you could write

```
data.reduce(function(o,n){ return o+(n.age/data.length) }, 0)
```

If you want to `SELECT sum(age) from json` you could write

```
data.reduce(function(o,n){ return o+n.age*1 },0)
```

So why not using, what the language gives you?

Edit: I saw, you specified your needs. What exactly is the transformation needed? I think there should be a JS-way, to do, what you want.

Edit2: For tabular representation, you have to do a `reduce` over all data. For the example I simplified a little bit:

```
var aaData=[{"country":"USA", "month":"1", "earnings":"1000"}, {"country":"USA", "month":"2", "earnings":"1001"},     {"country":"USA", "month":"3", "earnings":"1002"}, {"country":"Germany", "month":"1", "earnings":"1000"},     {"country":"Germany", "month":"2", "earnings":"1001"}, {"country":"Germany", "month":"3", "earnings":"1002"}]

var result=aaData.reduce(function(o, n){
    if (!o.hasOwnProperty(n.country)) o[n.country]={};
    o[n.country][n.month]=n.earnings;
    return o;
}, {})
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WxsRj/) to play with.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks, for the response but I do not have any control on the response / result from the backent that is why i need to manipulate it in json.. although i have encounter jsonsql which is pretty fine.. I believe it still lacking SUM and group by .. I think

Comment: When you have JSON, you have *J* ava *S* cript *O* bjects, which means, you could do, whatever JS gives you to manipulate these objects. Perhaps http://underscorejs.org/ is worth a look.

Comment: Hi Clannad. LINQ JS and TaffyDB (which are included in my answer) have sum and other aggregate functions. And considering that my answer also mention JSONSQL, i guess that she could be accepted =)

Comment: Hi Marcelo, thanks yes i saw it to but havent check them thoroughly because i believe they still lack the left join / sub queries.

Comment: @MarceloBezerra would you mind, using your own commenting section?

Comment: @ThomasJunk I do not understand exactly why you are asking this, but okay, no problem

Comment: I do not want to disturb your "private conversation" and do not want to get notified, when your "private conversation" updates ;)